# How to update pip by default added in the pyenv virtualenv

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, pyenv

When I create virtual environment using `pyenv` `virtualenv` the version of `pip` added along with it is `19.0.3`, however this is not the latest version anymore. I installed newer `pip` to the source environment, but this doesn't seem to affect what version is added in the `virtualenv`.

```
$ pyenv virtualenv 3.7.3 test-env
Looking in links: /var/folders/hl/mm_f1p2j3pg211388dkh_wvm2fkj9r/T/tmpiasxckc0
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /Users/narunas/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/envs/test-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages (40.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pip in /Users/narunas/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/envs/test-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages (19.0.3)
$ pyenv shell test-env
(test-env) $ pip --version
pip 19.0.3 from /Users/narunas/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/envs/test-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
(test-env) $ pyenv shell 3.7.3
$ pip --version
pip 19.1.1 from /Users/narunas/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
```